# A macro for unicode bold math font

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{R}
    \qquad
    
    \qquad
    \mbfR
    \qquad
    \mathbb{R}
    \qquad
    \mathfrak{R}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the above code using `lualatex`, I get a pdf with a line of five `R`s. If I copy the line from the pdf, I get the following result:

```
R


ℝ
ℜ
```

Is there a macro like `\mathbf` which produces proper unicode bold serif characters, similarly to how `\mathbb` and `\mathfrak` produce proper unicode blackboard resp. fraktur characters?

Comment: See `\symbf` in the `unicode-math` manual.

Comment: you should really use `\symbb` and `\symfrac` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `unicode-math` there are new, improved commands `\symbf`, `\symbb`, `\symfrak` etc.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  R\\
  \symup{R}\\
  \symbf{R}\\
  \symbb{R}\\
  \symfrak{R}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: different Rs]

See, e.g., section 5 of the `unicode-math` manual for more information about the advantages of these commands and table 7 for an overview of available `\sym…` commands.

Comment: Thank you! I'll upvote your answer as soon as I have enough reputation :)